# how to define xmlns namespace in HTML 5 or IE11

Tags: xml, html, internet-explorer, xhtml

I have existing  code `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:nav="nav:ns" >`  I am trying to find the equivalent code in html 5 .

I have several tags with same namespace  and CSS applied to the tags like
`<ns:top style="height:20px">` is not working. I am assuming this is due to  namespace registration. Please suggest.

Comment: That does not conform to HTML5. You could use a private extension of HTML5 to achieve that but how you do so depends on whether you are serving your resource with the `text/html` or the `application/xhtml+xml` media type. Consider using [custom elements](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

just add the html5 doctype or run your webpage through the w3 validator.
http://validator.w3.org/nu

see also https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/HTML_vs._XHTML